# How to listen status "pending" using Mern stack

Tags: express, mern

I have a Mern application, it works fine. But some operations takes time. I want to inform user while some network request in "pending" state. For example say "Please wait..." while doing some work on server side. Is there a way to check status "pending"?

Comment: Please provide some code so we can help you. In general, what you're looking for is `async` functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a state named loading and set it to true before you initiate the HTTP Request, once you get the response you can set the loading state to false and disable the loading message.